# wix Managed bootstrapper: Rollback failing

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix-extension, wix3.7

I have multiple EXECPackages chained in my managed bootstrapper, for example:

```
<ExePackage Id="Test1" SourceFile="D:\Test\TestBatch.bat" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" 
              InstallCommand="Testinstall1"
              UninstallCommand="Testuninstall1"
              />
<ExePackage Id="Test2" .../>
```

I want my rollback to execute the Uninstall command.
The generated log file has the following info:

> Rollback:uninstall.  Applying rollback package: Test2, action:
>   Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\AD944C8E8D75C79F57819C331F46D15B4CFD9172\TestBatch.bat,
>   arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\AD944C8E8D75C79F57819C331F46D15B4CFD9172\TestBatch.bat"
>   Testuninstall2' [24F4:246C][2013-06-05T14:45:10]e000: Error
>   0x80070003: Failed to CreateProcess on path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\AD944C8E8D75C79F57819C331F46D15B4CFD9172\TestBatch.bat
>   [24F4:246C][2013-06-05T14:45:10]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to
>   execute EXE package. [1654:27A8][2013-06-05T14:45:10]e000: Error
>   0x80070003: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

I realized that when rollback is triggered (`Result.Cancel`), the cached folder that contains the Exe package payload is deleted from `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache`.

However this used to work before.

Answer (score 3):

The `UninstallCommand` is executed on rollback if the package is being installed. I've seen this issue occur when the same executable is used for multiple `ExePackage` elements in a single `Chain`. The way that the Burn engine caches packages uses the hash of the executable to determine the location. Thus if you put the same executable in `Chain` it can be prematurely removed. Make sure every executable package is unique in your Bundle.

PS: It is highly recommended that you have a [DetectCondition on the ExePackage](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912167-How-the-DetectCondition-attribute-on-ExePackage-element-is-used-)